# i have an issue with parsing ini file using ini parser, am getting the output as key = value , what am looking to is something like this : Key=value

Tags: c#, parsing, ini

am using ini parser to read ini file and modify and create some keys based on user input, problem is am getting a format of (key = value) and what am looking to have is (key=value) as the application is sensitive to spaces.

here is the code i use.

```
    string iniFile = "custom_settings.ini";
var parser = new FileIniDataParser();

parser.Parser.Configuration.SkipInvalidLines = true;
parser.Parser.Configuration.KeyValueAssigmentChar = '=';
IniData data = parser.ReadFile(iniFile);


data["CONFIG"]["Account"]=account.Text.ToLower();
data["CONFIG"]["BaseEndpoint"]=baseEndpoint.Text.ToLower();
data["CONFIG"]["Locale"]=recognizer.Text.ToLower();
parser.WriteFile(iniFile, data);
```

Comment: Which application is sensitive to spaces? The application of which we see the code, or another application? Why is the application sensitive to spaces? INI files are typically not space sensitive with the Microsoft API What INI library are you using in the given code?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about *parsing* ini files; rather, it is about generating them (or generating a constrained version of ini files without whitespace).

Comment: INI files were created to be a simple as possible, and could be read and written with a single line of code.  Why anyone would need a wapper around this is beyond me.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments, other application that uses this ini file is sensitive to spaces (values will be ignored and defaulted to other values) if the format of the ini file is something like : (Key = value) instead it need a format of (key=value) to work. 
am not trying to create new ini file by this code, rather am trying to edit existing keys and create other new.

am using ini-parser 2.5 library.

Comment: i worked around this (maybe not the best solution) but it done the job by using Replace method.
`var allText = File.ReadAllText(iniFile);
                    allText = allText.Replace(" = ", "=");
                    File.WriteAllText(iniFile, allText);`

Answer (score 0):

```
FileIniDataParser.Parser.Configuration.AssigmentSpacer = ""
```